# mxGraph - disable vertex selection when dragging

Tags: javascript, graph, editor, mxgraph

I'm using JS mxGraph and would like to disable the auto selection of a vertex when dragging it. Vertex should only be selected if the user clicks on it without moving it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the following works

```
    mxGraphHandler.prototype.isDelayedSelection = function(cell, me) {
        return true;
    };

    mxGraphHandler.prototype.getCells = function(initialCell) {
        if (this.graph.getSelectionCells().includes(initialCell)) {
            return this.graph.getMovableCells(this.graph.getSelectionCells());
        }
        return this.graph.getMovableCells([initialCell]);
    };
```